# python repeated indexing into a list or a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of labels:

```
>> labels = ['Male', 'Female']
```

And a list of indices:

```
>> ii = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

I am trying to get the list of labels corresponding to the indices:

```
>> labels[ii]
```

This gave me an error. What I expect to get is:

```
['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male']
```

This is easy in Matlab.

I guess I can use list comprehension:

```
[labels[i] for i in ii]
```

Is there another more direct way to get this in python?

Comment: `np.take(labels,ii)`?

Comment: `[labels[i] for i in ii]` is the direct way to do this. Why do you not like that method? Speed? Readability?

Comment: Lists don't accept this kind of indexing, but numpy arrays do.  `np.take` converts `labels` to an array first.  The comprehension is good if you want to stick with a list (and may be faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lablels` is a numpy array e.g.

```
labels=numpy.array( ['Male', 'Female'])
```

you can simply write

```
labels[ii]
```

Output is

```
array(['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female',
       'Male', 'Male'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

Comment: You are correct. I did not try numpy array with the fancy indexing.